# Laravel returns request content with response

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, post, laravel-9

I have an API on Laravel, I did project some time ago, but now when I returned to it I have a problem. When I do POST request on API, I get response with request.
For example endpoint: https://ttr-api.somniumgame.com/api/user_info

I send for testing (can be any data) json data:

```
{
    "auth_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoiVGVzdCIsIm5pY2tuYW1lIjoiTG9vc2VyIiwiZGV2aWNlIjoiaW9zIiwiaXNzIjoiU29tbml1bUdhbWUiLCJhdWQiOiJ0dHItYXBpLnNvbW5pdW1nYW1lLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTY1MDE0MDE1MywiZXhwIjoxNjUwMTQwMjEzfQ.9nPgzn4wZEDGaN4rqvyW5mY5fZspt8HfUpm6lgzFin0"
}
```

I get response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.20.2
Date: Sun, 17 Apr 2022 07:22:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.3

{
    "auth_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoiVGVzdCIsIm5pY2tuYW1lIjoiTG9vc2VyIiwiZGV2aWNlIjoiaW9zIiwiaXNzIjoiU29tbml1bUdhbWUiLCJhdWQiOiJ0dHItYXBpLnNvbW5pdW1nYW1lLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTY1MDE0MDE1MywiZXhwIjoxNjUwMTQwMjEzfQ.9nPgzn4wZEDGaN4rqvyW5mY5fZspt8HfUpm6lgzFin0"
}{"error":"Expired token"}
```

But in my code controller do:

```
if (isset($data['error'])) return response()->json(['error' => $data['error']], 400);
```

Why I get 200 code instead of 400? Why I have request body inside response?

I have in Kernel:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\LogAfterRequest::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array<string, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'jwt.verify' => \App\Http\Middleware\JwtMiddleware::class,
    ];
}
```

I think it can be: \App\Http\Middleware\LogAfterRequest::class,
But when I comment this line nothing changes.
Code of this middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class LogAfterRequest {

    public function handle($request, \Closure  $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
        Log::info('app.requests', ['request' => $request->all(), 'response' => $response]);
    }

}
```

Where can be problem? I have no ideas...

P.S. When we use post request WITHOUT any body we got correct status code:
Can be tested here online now: https://reqbin.com

P.S.S. I use Nginx, maybe here can be problem but I nothing found what difference with other project API and it work fine...

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    proxy_read_timeout     1200;
    proxy_connect_timeout  240;
    client_max_body_size   0;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' '';
    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                                        html htm shtml;
    text/css                                         css;
    text/xml                                         xml;
    image/gif                                        gif;
    image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                           js;
    application/atom+xml                             atom;
    application/rss+xml                              rss;

    text/mathml                                      mml;
    text/plain                                       txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor                 jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                                 wml;
    text/x-component                                 htc;

    image/png                                        png;
    image/svg+xml                                    svg svgz;
    image/tiff                                       tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                               wbmp;
    image/webp                                       webp;
    image/x-icon                                     ico;
    image/x-jng                                      jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                                   bmp;

    font/woff                                        woff;
    font/woff2                                       woff2;

    application/java-archive                         jar war ear;
    application/json                                 json;
    application/mac-binhex40                         hqx;
    application/msword                               doc;
    application/pdf                                  pdf;
    application/postscript                           ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                                  rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl                    m3u8;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml             kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz                 kmz;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                         xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject                    eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                    ppt;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics      odg;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation  odp;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet   ods;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text          odt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                                                     pptx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                                                     xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                                                     docx;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc                         wmlc;
    application/x-7z-compressed                      7z;
    application/x-cocoa                              cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff                  jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file                     jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                           run;
    application/x-perl                               pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                              prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed                     rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager             rpm;
    application/x-sea                                sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash                    swf;
    application/x-stuffit                            sit;
    application/x-tcl                                tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert                       der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall                          xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                            xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                             xspf;
    application/zip                                  zip;

    application/octet-stream                         bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream                         deb;
    application/octet-stream                         dmg;
    application/octet-stream                         iso img;
    application/octet-stream                         msi msp msm;

    audio/midi                                       mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                                       mp3;
    audio/ogg                                        ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                                      m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                                ra;

    video/3gpp                                       3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                                       ts;
    video/mp4                                        mp4;
    video/mpeg                                       mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                                  mov;
    video/webm                                       webm;
    video/x-flv                                      flv;
    video/x-m4v                                      m4v;
    video/x-mng                                      mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                                   asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                                   wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                                  avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/office.somniumgame.com.conf:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name office.somniumgame.com www.office.somniumgame.com;
    return 301 https://office.somniumgame.com$request_uri;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  office.somniumgame.com www.office.somniumgame.com;
    root         /var/www/html/public;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt_office/live/office.somniumgame.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt_office/live/office.somniumgame.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass teamcity-linux-agent:9001;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/somniumgame.com.conf:
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name somniumgame.com www.somniumgame.com;
        return 301 https://somniumgame.com$request_uri;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name  somniumgame.com www.somniumgame.com;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt_root/live/somniumgame.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt_root/live/somniumgame.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
        }
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://teamcity-linux-agent:3000;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            client_max_body_size 100m;
        }
    }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/ttr-api.somniumgame.com.conf:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ttr-api.somniumgame.com www.ttr-api.somniumgame.com;
    return 301 https://ttr-api.somniumgame.com$request_uri;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  ttr-api.somniumgame.com www.ttr-api.somniumgame.com;
    root         /var/www/html/public;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt_ttr/live/ttr-api.somniumgame.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt_ttr/live/ttr-api.somniumgame.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass teamcity-linux-agent:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

P.S.S.S. I added this route and in this case we have same problem, I think problem not inside controller

```
Route::post('test', function () {
    return response()->json('SOME TEXT');
});

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.20.2
Date: Sun, 17 Apr 2022 09:44:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.3

{
    "auth_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoiVGVzdCIsIm5pY2tuYW1lIjoiTG9vc2VyIiwiZGV2aWNlIjoiaW9zIiwiaXNzIjoiU29tbml1bUdhbWUiLCJhdWQiOiJ0dHItYXBpLnNvbW5pdW1nYW1lLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTY1MDE0MDE1MywiZXhwIjoxNjUwMTQwMjEzfQ.9nPgzn4wZEDGaN4rqvyW5mY5fZspt8HfUpm6lgzFin0"
}"SOME TEXT"
```

Comment: please, show us your nginx config, can be dumped with `nginx -T`

Comment: @user973254 added Nginx config to question...

Comment: Show the controller function

Comment: @Mihai updated post, I added test route without any controller, but still have same problem... I think its not controller problem, or in this case still can be controller?

Comment: This is wild guessing but search for an auth controller or just globally search for string auth_token and see what comes up.There must be some kind of intermediary which adds the token.Not too helpful, i know.

Comment: @Mihai not only 'auth_token' added... any params send to any route will added params from request to response...
For example if I will send: 
`{
    "post": "test"
}`
to "api/test" endpoint I will get:
`{
    "post": "test"
}"SOME TEXT"`

Comment: @FunnyCOFE, Hi, I faced the same problem. How did you manage to solve it? Can you help me, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kinsing malware - reason of this problem...
Needs to delete line in crontab and delete everything in /tmp folder